# Best way to deserialize JSON dictionary with swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, parse-platform

I have an array column of parse dictionary objects that are in JSON. I am trying to find the best way to deserialize it And then use the information on a tableview Cell. Ive never used JSON before so thanks for the help!

Here is the Column..[image]

so far with this line of code i can print all the containing objects, but I haven't been able to deserialize it yet.

```
 let history: AnyObject? = poolHistory.valueForKey("serviceHistory")
 print("\(history)")
```

Comment: [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

SwiftyJSON is a very good library, more :

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON